# getting looped data in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel

I need to loop my cart data and get some part of it `like: title & price` for my 3rd party online payment.

Here is what I have:

```
$items = Cart::getContent();
        foreach($items as $item)
        {
            $item->id; // the Id of the item
            $item->name; // the name
            $item->price; // the single price without conditions applied
            $item->getPriceSumWithConditions(); // the subtotal with conditions applied
            $item->quantity; // the quantity
        }

        $items = [
            array(
                'id'        => 
                'price'     => 
                'quantity'  => 
                'name'      =>
            )
        ];
```

**My question is:**

How should I fill my arrays? I mean should I make something like:

`$id = $item->id;` in my foreach and then say `'id' => $id` or just say `'id' => $item->id` in my array?

> PS: I know this question might seem silly question to some of you but as I cannot
>   `dd` my results that's why i asked here, `why?` because my data goes to 3rd party website by
>   api and all i get is not getting result. so really can't dd it in my
>   front-end. that's why i asked here.

## SAMPLE

[sample video](https://streamable.com/8kgeu)

## UPDATE 2

I've changed my function like:

```
$items = Cart::getContent();
        foreach($items as $item)
        {
            array(
                'id'        => $item->id,
                'price'     => $item->getPriceWithConditions(),
                'quantity'  => $item->quantity,
                'name'      => $item->name,
            );
        }
```

> **Issue:** is that I still can't get my popup form as you see in my sample video above.

## Code

Here is my complete code:

```
public function payonline(){
        //   midtrans
        error_log('masuk ke snap token dri ajax');
        $midtrans = new Midtrans;

        $transaction_details = array(
            'order_id'      => uniqid(),
            'gross_amount'  => $request->input('totalPriceInTotal')
        );


        $items = Cart::getContent();
        foreach($items as $item)
        {
            array(
                'id'        => $item->id,
                'price'     => $item->getPriceWithConditions(),
                'quantity'  => $item->quantity,
                'name'      => $item->name,
            );
        }

        $orderaddress = $request->input('address_id');
        // Populate customer's shipping address
        $shipping_address = array(
            'first_name'    => $request->input('buyer_name'),
            'last_name'     => $request->input('buyer_name'),
            'address'       => $orderaddress->address,
            'city'          => $orderaddress->city->name,
            'postal_code'   => $orderaddress->postalcode,
            'phone'         => $request->input('phone'),
            'country_code'  => 'IDN'
            );

        // Populate customer's Info
        $customer_details = array(
            'first_name'      => $request->input('buyer_name'),
            'last_name'       => $request->input('buyer_name'),
            'email'           => $request->input('buyer_email'),
            'phone'           => $request->input('phone'),
            'billing_address' => $shipping_address,
            'shipping_address'=> $shipping_address
            );

        // Data yang akan dikirim untuk request redirect_url.
        $credit_card['secure'] = true;
        //ser save_card true to enable oneclick or 2click
        //$credit_card['save_card'] = true;

        $time = time();
        $custom_expiry = array(
            'start_time' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s O",$time),
            'unit'       => 'hour', 
            'duration'   => 2
        );

        $transaction_data = array(
            'transaction_details'=> $transaction_details,
            'item_details'       => $items,
            'customer_details'   => $customer_details,
            'credit_card'        => $credit_card,
            'expiry'             => $custom_expiry
        );

        try
        {
            $snap_token = $midtrans->getSnapToken($transaction_data);
            //return redirect($vtweb_url);
            echo $snap_token;
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {   
            return $e->getMessage;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you do `foreach($items as &$item)` you can modify the items and the changes will stick.

Comment: @ceejayoz meaning?

Comment: Can you add sample output you want ?

Comment: It seems like you are trying to push array element to an object.

Comment: @SagarGautam sure, wait.

Comment: @mafortis Meaning your code appears to be trying to build a new `$items` array, but you already have one you can modify in-place instead.

Comment: @SagarGautam updated.

Comment: @ceejayoz so i must put my foreach inside `$items =[]` or what exactly?

Comment: If you're just trying to convert the cart objects to an array: `$items = json_decode(json_encode(Cart::getContent()), true);`

Comment: @btl is not about converting, is about getting copy of existed data. my data is already converted by `casts`

Comment: still I don't understand what you want other here might know

Comment: That would give you a copy of the carts contents.

Comment: @SagarGautam I want to get my items title and price from cart to this function.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: @btl the question here that make me confused is: should i put my `foreach` inside `array(` or remove `array(` totally..... ?

Comment: Any way I don't understand. Have you solved your previous problem ?

Comment: @SagarGautam not remember which one you talking about :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumming that all of the formats you mentioned in your code is correct to the 'Midtrans' API specification, then all you need is to assign an array variable to your foreach loop of your items like this:

```
$items = Cart::getContent();
$item_details = array();
        foreach($items as $item)
        {
            $item_details[] = array(
                'id'        => $item->id,
                'price'     => $item->getPriceWithConditions(),
                'quantity'  => $item->quantity,
                'name'      => $item->name,
            );
        }
```

Then replace your transaction data with the formatted array $item_details

```
$transaction_data = array(
            'transaction_details'=> $transaction_details,
            'item_details'       => $item_details,
            'customer_details'   => $customer_details,
            'credit_card'        => $credit_card,
            'expiry'             => $custom_expiry
        );
```

Comment: i get this on my network `/payonline?_=1518579844775` message: `Undefined variable: request`

Comment: Then you'll have to check/var_dump your $request to see what's in it, my answer is just to assign your item variable accordingly

Answer (score 0):

something like this..

```
$items = Cart::getContent();
            $yourItems = [];
            foreach($items as $item)
            {
                $data = ['id' => '','price'=> '', 'quantity'  => '', 'name' =>'', ];

                $data = ['id'] = $item->id; // the Id of the item
                $data = ['name'] = $item->name; // the name
                $data = ['price'] = $item->price; // the single price without conditions applied
                $data = ['quantity'] =  $item->quantity; // the quantity

array_push($yourItems, $data);
            }
```

Comment: Assignments can only happen to writable values